# Creating array of integers in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I have a vector of integer values, `vector<Value*> myIntegers` in my LLVM code (not necessarily constant). I want to create a Store instruction to store these integers. To create the store instruction using the format below, for the first argument I need to create a Value* pointing to these integers (create an array out of them).

```
new StoreInst(Value *Val, Value *Ptr, ...);
```

If my integers were constants I would have used:

```
Constant *IntArrayConstant = ConstantDataArray::get(getGlobalContext(), ArrayRef<Value*> myIntegers);
```

How can I create a generic array of `i32` types, with a `Value*` pointing to it? The documentation says storing ArrayRef is not safe either.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`VectorType::get()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1VectorType.html#ab43657ed1abe2e2ed3a6a394f233ebd0), create an [`UndefValue`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1UndefValue.html#a4c7b693ae173afe8da954bdf01c2b52e) of the type you just obtained, and then populate it with N [`InsertElementInst`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1InsertElementInst.html)s, with N the number of elements. You will then create a `StoreInst` to store the `Value*` on the heap.

The result of the last `InsertElementInst` will thus be the `Value*` you are looking for (i.e. a vector containing the values). Please note that, depending on what you're trying to do, the `StoreInst` might actually be not needed at all.

Note that I'm assuming that all your `Value`s have the same underlying type (i.e. `getType()` returns the same result for all of them).

Edit: also note that maybe, depending on what you're trying to do, it could be more appropriate to use `ArrayType::get` instead of `VectorType::get`.